# Is it possible for an ambiguous CFG convert into CNF and becomes unambiguous?

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation-theory, context-free-language, chomsky-normal-form

Is it possible for an ambiguous context-free grammar(CFG) to convert into Chomsky Normal Form(CNF) and becomes unambiguous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. All you really need is a single example to show this is possible. Consider the ambiguous grammar

```
S :- A | B
A :- a
B :- a
```

This grammar is equivalent to the following grammar in CNF

```
S :- a
```

This grammar is not ambiguous.

Comment: Is the grammar first ambiguous because "a" has two leftmost derivations (1) A :- a, S :- A and (2) B :- b; S :- B?

Comment: Yes, two distinct derivations produce the string a: S -> A -> a and S -> B -> a. The parse trees are different but the string derived is the same.